# Grep logs for occurrences per second

Tags: linux, sed, grep

I am trying to search logs for a range of time looking for the number of occurrences a specific account has.  For instance I am running this now:

```sh
sed ‘/23:50:28/,/23:55:02/! d’ log.log | grep account_number | wc -l
```

Which nicely returns the total number of times this account might have entries given the time frame per second.  My question is how can I also get a list of all those occurrences by each time entry?  Example:

```
23:50:28 - 2
23:50:29 - 1
23:50:30 - 3
etc.
etc.
```

Thanks

Comment: different accounts in each second or what? you need to show the input and your desired output. if you can't disclose your log content, you should make up some fake ones for us to deal with your problem.

Comment: Same account.  entries per second. With the provided example i can search for an account number between those times and get the total number of entries

Comment: check out `uniq -c`. see if it does the job for you?

Comment: as i said, the command will heavily rely on how your data looks like. so do provide a bogus input to allow exact answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk ‘/23:50:28/,/23:55:02/{if(/account_number/) a[$1]++}
     END{for(k in a) print k " - " a[k]}' log | sort
```

obviously not tested since there is no sample input.

Comment: Thank thats great.  It works but is not printing those time stamps just all the information before it.  So instead of say "23:50:28 -" I see the beginning of the log text like "live2.internal:4535253 - 3".  Steps in the right direction at least!

Comment: this prints the whole line, not clear from your question what the file looks lime and you're not doing any filtering either.  I assumed the time stamp is the first field, if not change `$1` to the correct index.

Comment: Yeah its a perfectly fair response since I wasn't super clear.  But this is just what I needed.

Comment: Would it be great, if given awk script is explained, so anyone can be able to write version for "grouping" by minute/hour/day...